# Can not delete cookie on some browser of some PC

Tags: php, cookies

I have one code set one cookie like this:

```html
<?php
setcookie("quiz", '{"fullname": "toanle", "age": 21}', 0, '/');
?>
```

And when i try delete i use:

```html
<?php
setcookie("quiz", "", time()-86400, '/');
?>
```

But i got some error on some browser can not delete that, almost browser is working, only some pc can not work.
I use vps form cloudways.com.
I hope someone can help.
Thanks all!

Comment: Please update your question with the error message.

Comment: @PetrHejda thanks for replied but ask me see nothing error message, i only see it's not work. :(